# Analog input to ATMEGA328P using op-amp - how does this circuit work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, single-supply-op-amp

I was looking for a good solution in order to use a bunch of components and read 0-10V/0-20mA and digital inputs using my Arduino Pro Mini (ATMEGA328P working at 3.3V.)

I've found online this schematic from SferaLabs, the reference board is [Iono Arduino](https://www.sferalabs.cc/product/iono-arduino/), here you can find the entire [schematic](https://www.sferalabs.cc/files/ionoard/doc/ionoard-sch.pdf), and following the interesting section:

[image: Multi-mode-inputs]

I find this schematic really interesting, it seems that, using a single op-amp, is able to manage: a digital input **OR** 0-10V analog input **OR** 0-20mA analog input *(as reported at page 8 of the board [user manual](https://www.sferalabs.cc/files/ionoard/doc/ionoard-user-guide.pdf))*:

[image: user-manual]

Now, I need to know two things:

- If I wire 3.3V at *BAT54S* cathode (red circle in the main photo) and the *VLIM* of the *LM224D*, will the circuit work without any issue?
- Can anyone help me to understand how this non inverting op-amp was configured in order to work like that?

Comment: You would need to adapt the gain of the opamp if it was designed to output an analog value 0-5V to suit new requirement 0-3.3V. Altrough I didn't check what is the original output voltage range.

Comment: The opamp is simply a voltage buffer, the opamp measures the voltage at its + input and then copies the same voltage to its output.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, you can read (at page 6) "compatible with 5.0V and 3.3V operating voltage Arduino boards with 1.0 pinout"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solving for V2: Vout=Vin * R2/(R1+R2)= Vin* 0.3299

So at 10V at V2 you get 3.3V output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHA7AT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Solving for I2:

Vout = I2*165

Vout = 20mA*165 = 3.3V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM2SQh.png)</sup>

In order to use this circuit with 3.3V supply, you should use a rail to rail opamp in order to maximize the output range and then recalculate resistors, so that the output voltage would be in range of the max. output of opamp. For example, instead to have a voltage divider of 0.33 for V2, you use a divider of 0.3. At 10V input you get only 3V output, you loose that 0.3 voltage range of ADC.

[image]

You can see, that LM224D can output only Vcc-1.5V, so not suitable for you, if you don't supply it with at least 5V.

EDIT:

If you will use the 3.3V supply, then also a 2.2k output limiting resistor is not needed.

EDIT2:

Recalculate resistors for 0-3V output voltage:

1. \$R_{shunt}=\frac{3V}{20mA} = 150 \Omega\$, so the same R54, without/shorted  R32(15 Ohm).
2. From solving for V2. R2=47.15, R1=?

$$0.3= \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

$$0.3\cdot(R_1+R_2)= R_2$$

$$0.3\cdot R_1+0.3\cdot R_2= R_2$$

$$0.3\cdot R_1= R_2\cdot (1-0.3)$$

$$ R_1= R_2\frac{0.7}{0.3}= R_2\cdot 2.333$$

$$ R_1= 110.01 k\Omega$$

$$ R_{50}= 110.01-2\cdot47= 16.01k\Omega \approx 16k\Omega$$

Comment: So Marko, what op-amp you suggest to use? and which resistor values i have to use? please help me to figure out :)

Comment: @VirtApp Try to google first: "low offset rail to rail quad op amp single supply". Then choose your candidates, the drift, temp. stability matters for the price.

Comment: Maybe something like a lmv324 may be a good choice? which resistor values i need to use? i'm little bit in difficult on how to recalculate the resistor...

Comment: @VirtApp lmv324  is not a good choice, since the input signal has to be max. Vcc-1V.

Comment: Maybe the OP495 is a good pick, I've searched for and it seems quite good, I've looked at offset voltage...I'm on the right track?

Comment: If i've understood everything, the resistors will become: R50: 16.2k (as commercial value), the R32 will be removed, also the R36 will be removed. all the other resistors will be untouched,i'm right?

Comment: Also about the OPAMP, i've picked this one (TLV274), it's a Rail to rail, single power supply and low offset, you can check here: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Texas-Instruments-TI-TLV274CPWR_C9914.pdf

Comment: @VirtApp What about MCP6009, it has 80mV ouput voltage swing? Or LMV324A? There are so many, the TLV274 seems to have too large output voltage swing, OP495 is expensive but low voltage offset,...and so on. It depends on precision VS. price you want. Note, that also resistors 0.1% are expensive.

Comment: But the LMV324A report this on the datasheet: "The input common-mode voltage range of the LMV3xxA family extends100 mV beyond the negative supply rail and within 1 V below the positiverail for the full supply voltage rangeof 2.5 V to 5.5 V", so, i can use the LMV324A?...maybe i've not understood your previous sentences!

Comment: Also, JLCPCB has only a small amount of parts...you would be very kind if you can give me some part reference that i can check if JLCPB has them available or not...many thanks mate!

Comment: @VirtApp https://jlcpcb.com/parts/componentSearch?searchTxt=LMV324A

Comment: This is weird, in previous messages you told me that the LMV324 is not a good pick! i'm wrong?

Comment: About resistors, they become: R50: 16.2k (as commercial value), the R32 will be removed, also the R36 will be removed. all the other resistors will be untouched,i'm right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119866/discussion-between-virtapp-and-marko-bursic).

Comment: @VirtApp LMV324 is not LMV324A. You can leave the R36, also you can reserve a footprint for the capacitor from end to GND, it may be useful for filtering. You could look, possibly to remove R47 and R19.

Comment: Thanks, about the other resistors: R50 will become 16,2k and the others i'll leave untouched?

Comment: maybe after all those comments i think that it's better to edit your answer in order document better everything...also, i've not yet understood why you have recalculated the resistor for 0-3V when the battery voltage is 3.3V

Comment: @VirtApp The rail to rail opamp can output voltage near the rail voltage, but not 100%. It can output Vcc-swing. I have recalculated so that worst case swing is 0.3V, since you didn't know which opamp to use . You may recalculate the resistors according to spec. of opamp. I would recommend to use all of the resistors as original, then you place 0R or open if not needed.

Comment: Marko, i'm thinking about a different solution in order to keep the full scale 0-3.3V...if i leave the original resistors and opamp (LM224D) and i'll use a step up converter like the MCP1640T in order to pump 5V from 3.3V maybe all problem were solved...right?

Comment: @VirtApp The LM224 is the extended-temperature version of the cheap LM324, and below 25 °C, the common-mode input range ends at Vcc-2V. So simply using any cheap rail-to-rail opamp (e.g., TLV9001, TC75S103F, NCS2006) at 3.3 V is safe.

Comment: @CL., so, if i consider to use the NCS2006, i don't have to change anything else, right?

Comment: No, just use it with 3.3 V.